# Store counter values local and secure

Tags: c#, security, license-key

I want to store a value (counter) of my application (C#) on the client's machine in a way, that he/she can not manipulate or reset it. I thought about storing it parallel in the database (MSSQL), the registry and in a file. And if one value is lost (deleted) I've two bakcup options to restore the counter. Ok, if the user delete all three values simultaneously, the counter is reset to zero. That's an option I could live with.
But I wonder if there are any other concepts or best practices for storing values secure locally ... may be I only use the wrong search terms. Any hints?
Many Thanks!
Konrad

Comment: If you don't want a user to be able to manipulate a particular piece of data, you need to keep that data on a machine that you control (and, obviously, not then provide a means for the user to ask your machine to perform bad manipulation)

Comment: The only way to store a counter "securely" on the client would be to use efuses integrated into the machine. Even then a soldering iron could fix that. The sad fact is that this is the "trusted computing" problem.

Comment: Manipulating shouldn't be impossible but that hard and annoying to perform it twice or more a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No chance.

I start your application within my VMware image, where all changes are reverted when i close it. After a *restart* of the VM i have a fresh machine that never seen your application (or counters).

Even if you take multiple places where you store your informations. Which one wins if all these counters are having different values?

To get non-manipulatable counters you have to store them on your server and provide an API to your client application to read or increase that value.

Comment: Ok. That's point. But at least the database is running in an environment, that can't be easily reverted, since there are productive and continuous data in it, that will be lost if the complete machine is reverted to a previous state.